# GameHelper onConnected ConnectionHint is outdated

Tags: android

My app is a game where players take alternating turns, and it uses the BaseGameUtils class and some code from the examples.
When a user clicks on a notification (saying it is his turn in a match), the matchdata is passed to `onSignInSucceeded` (which is called in `onStart` by `GameHelper`). The problem is that when a user leaves the application and reenters it (so `onStop` and `onStart` are called), the data from the (old) intent is passed to `onSignInSucceeded`. That's a problem when the user already took a turn and the state of the board changed, because what he will see after reentering is the state before he took his turn. I tried to save the current state in `onSaveInstanceState`, but it still isn't passed to `GameHelper`s `onConnected`.

Is there a way to modify the hint that `onConnected` receives (and know what the origin of the hint is) or to dismiss a hint once it used in some way, so future restarts won't use it again?

Maybe I could compare the gamestate of the hint and the current game, but that may not always be possible, since the current game doesn't have to be the same game as the one from the intent, and in that case I can't easily get the (real) turn-number of the intents match and compare it to the turn-number stored in the intent.

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(getApiClient(), this);


    log("onSingInSucceeded called!");
    myPlayerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient());
    TurnBasedMatch match = mHelper.getTurnBasedMatch();
    if (match != null) {
        log("updated match from connection hint");
        updateMatch(match);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution:
We have to clear the stored notification data after we use it, so we can't use it on a later moment:

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(getApiClient(), this);

log("onSingInSucceeded called!");
myPlayerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient());
TurnBasedMatch match = mHelper.getTurnBasedMatch();
mHelper.clearTurnBasedMatch();   //<------------------------This is the solution
if (match != null) {
    log("updated match from connection hint");
    updateMatch(match);
    return;
}
}
```